# Jersey - How to pass SecurityContext across request

Tags: java, jersey

In Jersey `RequestFilter`, how can I set the `SecurityContext` such that it will be used in subsequent requests as well?

I have tried `RequestContext.setSecurityContext(securityContext)`. This sets only in the current request. How can set it such that it will be used across the request (in that session)?

Comment: What do you mean by setting SecurityContext to subsequent requests? Once you have a filter that sets the context you should be fine. And you don't want to set the same context for each request - what if the requests were invoked by different users?

Comment: If you're trying to get the session to do some kind of security check you can inject the HttpServletRequest which will allow you to access the session with the syntax like @Context HttpServletRequest request